# sending html input array with requests lib

Tags: python, python-requests

How can I send an html array with python requests lib?

There is CURL request example which I want realize with requests lib API:

```
curl <some url there>  -H <some header there> --data 'path[]=/empty&path[]=/Burns.docx&path[]=/Byron.doc'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `params` keyword takes a dictionary representing query parameters; if you give a key a *list* of values, then each of those values is represented as a separate entry in the query string. The `[]` suffix on names is a PHP / Ruby-on-Rails convention, you'll need to supply it yourself:

```
params = {'path[]': ['/empty', '/Burns.docx', '/Byron.doc']}
headers = {'Some-header', 'Header value'}
response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
```

Here the `path[]` parameter is given a list of values, each becomes a separate `path[]=<value>` entry in the query string.

Demo:

```
>>> import requests
>>> params = {'path[]': ['/empty', '/Burns.docx', '/Byron.doc']}
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/get'
>>> response = requests.get(url, params=params)
>>> response.url
u'http://httpbin.org/get?path%5B%5D=%2Fempty&path%5B%5D=%2FBurns.docx&path%5B%5D=%2FByron.doc'
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(response.json())
{u'args': {u'path[]': [u'/empty', u'/Burns.docx', u'/Byron.doc']},
 u'headers': {u'Accept': u'*/*',
              u'Accept-Encoding': u'gzip, deflate, compress',
              u'Connection': u'close',
              u'Host': u'httpbin.org',
              u'User-Agent': u'python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.6 Darwin/13.2.0',
              u'X-Request-Id': u'3e4c8341-3da9-4a26-9527-f983904b3b18'},
 u'origin': u'84.92.98.170',
 u'url': u'http://httpbin.org/get?path[]=%2Fempty&path[]=%2FBurns.docx&path[]=%2FByron.doc'}
```